# Extract the word after a digit from the string

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp, data-science

I have 1000 rows of strings. I would like to extract the words from a string based on a condition in python.

Eg: '1. Sprite (9x)::=2. Coffee::=    Cream (10x)::=    Sugar (10x)::=    Small::=3. Packet of Black Sugar (6x)'

Output Should be as :

-> Sprite, Coffee, Packet Of Black Sugar.

Like I would like to extract the word after the digits 1.,2.,3. and remove all the words before and after followed by special characters.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = '1. Sprite (9x)::=2. Coffee::= Cream (10x)::= Sugar (10x)::= Small::=3. Packet of Black Sugar (6x)'
matches = re.findall(r'\d+\. (\w+(?: \w+)*)', inp)
print(matches)  # ['Sprite', 'Coffee', 'Packet of Black Sugar']
```

Comment: @HAthedatascientist I have answered the question you actually asked above.  If you have some other requirements you should open a new question at this point.